# Usb hard disk suddenly not showing up in lsusb, fdisk, and /dev

Tags: boot, usb, mount, hard-drive

This is on Ubuntu server 20.04
Used to work, then the HDD mount point wouldn't open suddenly so I unmounted it,
seemed to fail from logs, and after the restart not detected. It's detected in other machines, haven't tried it on other Linux machines tho, but on a Windows machine while it couldn't be read or mounted since ext4, it's detected

I've read that the HDD may still think it's suspended so suspending the machine and on again might help but currently not willing to do that since I don't have physical access right of now.

Logs :
6:11 Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/48415a03-1dae-47f1-81c4-ea44687d18bd.
6:11 dev-disk-by\x2duuid-48415a03\x2d1dae\x2d47f1\x2d81c4\x2dea44687d18bd.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-48415a03\x2d1dae\x2d47f1\x2d81c4\x2dea44687d18bd.device/start timed out.

Dmesg | tail shows this
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBJxQ.png)

Comment: "seemed to fail from logs" ⇠ could you [edit] your question to share some of those logs? There is simply not enough information in the question to offer you anything of value at this point 

Comment: Added. There, timed out

Answer (score 0):

Update, it now just works again.
first of all, FYI that i tried plugging and unplugging multiple times, this time i have another linux machine i can access and tried it on that, it worked, plugged it back in on my server and works.

don't know why don't know how